# How do i get the list of connected usb devices in android programmatically ? The following code didn't work

Tags: android

```
public class HardwareActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.missilelauncher.USB_PERMISSION";
    private PendingIntent PermissionIntent;
    private Button button;
    private ImageView back;
    private TextView textInfo;
    private UsbDevice usbDevice;
    private UsbManager usbManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String action = getIntent().getAction();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hardware);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check);
        back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back);
        textInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usb_info);
        back.setOnClickListener(this);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED) || intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)) {
            Log.d("USB DEVICE ", " device attached");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED) || intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED)) {
            Log.d("USB DEVICE ", " device detached");
        }
    }

    private void checkInfo() {
        usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        PermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
                ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = usbManager.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
        String deviceString = "";
        while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
            usbDevice = deviceIterator.next();
            deviceString += "\n" + "DeviceID: " + usbDevice.getDeviceId() + "\n" +
                    "DeviceName: " + usbDevice.getDeviceName() + "\n" +
                    "DeviceClass: " + usbDevice.getDeviceClass() + " - " +
                    "VendorID: " + usbDevice.getVendorId() + "\n" +
                    "ProductID: " + usbDevice.getProductId() + "\n" ;
        }
        Log.d("USB Info", "USB " + deviceString);
        textInfo.setText(deviceString);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your device has a system permissions

android.hardware.usb.host.xml inside /system/etc/permissions/

To enable USB host API support you should add a file named android.hardware.usb.host.xml and containing the following lines:

```
<permissions>
```

into folder

/system/etc/permissions
in that folder find file named

handheld_core_hardware.xml or tablet_core_hardware.xml
and add

```
<feature name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
into <permissions> section.
```

Reboot your device. USB host API should work.

Procedure:
adb pull /system/etc/permissions/tablet_core_hardware.xml

Update that file and create android.hardware.usb.host.xml as specified

adb push android.hardware.usb.host.xml /system/etc/permissions
adb push tablet_core_hardware.xml /system/etc/permissions
Reboot.